# Cannot connect react native app w/ remote redux devtools

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-devtools-extension

I cannot connect my react-native app using redux to [redux-devtools-extension](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension) through [remote-redux-devtools](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/remote-redux-devtools).

I am using android device connected by USB on macOSX Sierra.

```
// configureStore.js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'remote-redux-devtools';
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";

const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({ realtime: true });

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    composeEnhancers(
      applyMiddleware(thunk),
    )
  );

  if (module.hot) {
    // Enable hot module replacement for reducers
    module.hot.accept(() => {
      const nextRootReducer = require('./reducers/index').default;
      store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
    });
  }

  return store;
};
```

Redux is correctly configured into the app, w/ a simple button action to update redux state.

But it cannot found any store.

[image: no redux store found]

What am I missing ?

Comment: i have same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

`const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose`